# Google LineChart - How to draw vertical axis line based on a max value. Lines stops before the max value

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a Google LineChart where I need to draw the vertical axis lines based on a max value. Here is the scenario:

```
var options = {
   vAxis: {
     viewWindow: {
       min: 0,
       max: verticalAxisMaxValue // for my case it is 789. but could be anything.
     },
     gridlines: {
       count: 10 // or something else
     }
   }
}
```

The value of `verticalAxisMaxValue` is determined before `options` is declared.

What I need is to draw the vertical axis lines to be drawn up to `verticalAxisMaxValue` (**it could be anything like 789, 858, 560, ...**) The problem I am having is the axis lines are being drawn but the line with the highest value never goes up to the `verticalAxisMaxValue`.

Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Here the highest value is 700, but I need to draw a line at 789. And the similar should happen for any `verticalAxisMaxValue`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewWindow` controls the visible range of the axis,
not necessarily the labels displayed on the axis.

to control the labels, you need to supply the `ticks` option.

the `ticks` option is an array of values, of the same type as on the axis.
it could be date, number, etc.

in this case, we can use the max value to build our ticks.

you will need to determine how much each label should increment by,
such as 100

here, we set the max, then add a tick for each 100 under the max,
then add the max as well to the ticks.

```
var verticalAxisMaxValue = 789;
var ticks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < verticalAxisMaxValue; i = i + 100) {
  ticks.push(i);
}
ticks.push(verticalAxisMaxValue);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'GROWTH TARGET'],
    ['Apr', 145],
    ['May', 169],
    ['Jun', 201],
    ['Jul', 231],
    ['Aug', 281],
    ['Sep', 325],
    ['Oct', 369],
    ['Nov', 444],
    ['Dec', 478]
  ]);

  var verticalAxisMaxValue = 789;
  var ticks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < verticalAxisMaxValue; i = i + 100) {
    ticks.push(i);
  }
  ticks.push(verticalAxisMaxValue);

  var options = {
    vAxis: {
      ticks: ticks,
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: verticalAxisMaxValue
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton once again @WhiteHat! I actually got this working and most importantly almost exactly the same way you suggested. :) Meanwhile, I would request you to please give me a solution for the other problem I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731384/google-columnchart-how-to-move-annotation-text-horizontally-beyond-the-chart-a